# Looking for the name for an abstract class that models functions as objects

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented

In mathematics, adding two functions can be considered an operation in the space of functions. The result is another function.

I can model this by making functions an abstract class and implement all relevant operators for it. An object of that class can be assigned with basic functions (e.g. a constant) and the operators can be used to construct more complex functions. Those objects can be e.g. evaluated or differentiated

What would be a proper name for such an abstract class? Obviously *function* is a perfectly adequate term in the mathematical sense but ambiguous in programming.

I vaguely remember someone calling it *functor* but researching that term lead to something different.

Comment: Re: "Those objects can be e.g. evaluated or differentiated": Differentiation makes this trickier. Are you OK with approximating it by `(f(x) + f(x + h)) / h` for some small `h`? If not, then I think you'll need some sort of *symbolic* representation of functions, rather than having an abstract method encapsulating a computation that you can't "peer into".

Comment: "but ambiguous in programming" - sure, it might be confusing to some random person who stumbled upon your code, but, if you take the perspective that code is written for to be read by other people, then when choosing names/concepts/etc., take into account who's your intended programmer audience. 1/2

Comment: People who are going to make use of your code will presumably do so precisely because it lets them represent mathematical functions, i.e. they will be interested in working in that domain. They'll think in those terms, they'll read your documentation, etc. *They* are not going to be confused, and they'll appreciate that  you're using terminology that's straightforward to them. So, don't write for the broadest audience imaginable - chose some baseline, and go with that. 2/2

Comment: @ruakh I mean symbolic representation. Operators will build a syntax tree for an expression at runtime. Such an “function object“ can be passed as parameter to a (normal) function that performs the differentiation.

Comment: @HartmutBraun: Ah, I see. In that case, Jörg W Mittag's very thorough answer is probably not really relevant to you. :-/

Comment: @FilipMilovanović I was rather looking for the name used in computer science for the *concept* of using functions as objects. I assumed that there might be a standard name for it.

Comment: @HartmutBraun "*the name used in computer science for the concept of using functions as objects*" - you might be thinking of [first-class functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function) (in OOP at least, since of course a "first-class value" is an object there). But really, a standard name for modelling mathematical functions as objects in a CAS? That's just standard OOP modelling, no specific terminology for that.

Comment: I see. I don't think there is. You're representing (modeling) mathematical functions as objects, but that's what objects *do* - they represent things/concepts, and we name the type to indicate what we intended to model. There's no real reason why modeling functions (as opposed to users, bank accounts, loggers, etc.) would warrant a special name.

Comment: Another problem is that many terms are generally not consistent across an entire discipline (people in different subfields/contexts use same terms slightly differently) - this is pretty common, it happens more often then you'd think (and is, incidentally, one of the driving motivations behind bounded contexts around ubiquitous languages in DDD). One example you've come across is "functor". Another one is "function" vs "map" in mathematics (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#Other_terms))

Comment: @Bergi: +1 for first-class functions. I think it matches OP's description pretty well.

Comment: @EricDuminil - Check the OPs comment above, it seems that first-class functions are not what the OP is talking about *at all*. P.S. The fact that we came to the opposite conclusion highlights how it can be hard to communicate ideas :D

Comment: If you look at the functions more as _data_ and allow this data to have any dimensionality (like Tensors), you could think of (compositions, derivatives, etc., of) functions as Tensor operations. This is what _TensorFlow_ does :) I am not suggesting a name here, but perhaps you'll have another idea if you think of you're future program as something else.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović "not at all" seems harsh. Since python functions are first-class, it should be possible to define `def f(x):`, `def g(x):`, and then use them in `diff(f + g)`, for example. It might be hard to monkey-patch the built-in `function` class, but `diff(add(f, g))` should definitely be possible. What are `f` and `g`? First-class functions. And OP could build more complex functions using those.

Comment: @EricDuminil I didn't mean to sound harsh, just used it to amplify my point about different interpretations. While it's true that you could use first-class functions as a *mechanism* to do what you described, the concept of first-class functions does not entirely encompass / align with what the OP seems to have in mind (e.g., it doesn't by itself include symbolic representation of mathematical functions, although you could build one out of fc funcs), and the OP wants the concept. It's "[programmer] functions as first-class feature" vs "structure/object representing a [mathematical] function".

Comment: If "function" is the most natural word in math jargon then is the right name to go. Developers deal with this sort of ambiguity all the time no matter the domain, so you should not be worried about that. You can clear the ambiguity by writing down comments or source code documentation.

Comment: Thanks everybody for the interesting discussion. With the answers given by Jörg Mittag and Christophe it seems to me that lambda term/lambda expressions is the name for the concept I’m looking for. In the Java example that Jörg provided the corresponding interface is simply called „Function“.

Comment: [The names Java uses, organized into tables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27743315/1493294)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can take a look at what other people are doing:

- Java calls the package which contains the various function types [`java.util.function`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/package-summary.html). Since Java does not support "generic overloading" (i.e. multiple generic types with the same name but different type parameters), it has separate types for functions with different parameter and return types, for example [`java.util.function.Function`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Function.html) for a unary function, [`java.util.function.Consumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Consumer.html) for a unary `void` function (i.e. a unary function which returns no value), [`java.util.function.Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Supplier.html) for a nullary function, [`java.util.function.Predicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Predicate.html) for a Boolean function as well as different arity, for example [`java.util.function.BiFunction`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/BiFunction.html) for a binary function, [`java.util.function.BiConsumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/BiConsumer.html) for a binary `void` function (i.e. a binary function which returns no value), [`java.util.function.BiPredicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/BiPredicate.html) for a binary Boolean function, plus function types for primitives which cannot be abstracted over by generics, for example [`java.util.function.DoubleToIntFunction`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/DoubleToIntFunction.html) or [`java.util.function.DoubleToLongFunction`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/DoubleToLongFunction.html).
- Scala also does not allow abstracting over the number of type parameters, and so has separate function types for each arity, which are called `scala.FunctionN` where *N* is the arity of the function, for example [`scala.Function0`](https://scala-lang.org/api/3.1.2/scala/Function0.html), [`scala.Function1`](https://scala-lang.org/api/3.1.2/scala/Function1.html), [`scala.Function2`](https://scala-lang.org/api/3.1.2/scala/Function2.html), etc.
- Kotlin calls it [`kotlin.Function`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-function.html)
- Haskell calls the module which contains all the function manipulation [`Data.Function`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Function.html)
- C# can abstract over the number of type parameters and does not have primitive types, but it cannot abstract over "`void`-ness", so it has two function types. It calls `void` functions [`System.Action`](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.action-2) and non-`void` functions [`System.Func`](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.func-2).

> I vaguely remember someone calling it *functor* but researching that term lead to something different.

Remember that a word means only what the person using the word wants it to mean. Nothing more, nothing less.

In this particular case, there are at least three distinct meanings in three distinct contexts, I am aware of:

- In mathematics, specifically *category theory*, a *functor* is (roughly speaking) "something which can be mapped over" or "computation with context". This is also the way the word is used in many programming language communities, for example in [Haskell](https://wiki.haskell.org/Typeclassopedia#Functor), Scala (e.g. [cats](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/functor.html) and [Scalaz](https://scalaz.github.io/7/typeclass/)), and [Python](https://github.com/dbrattli/OSlash/wiki/Functors,-Applicatives,-And-Monads-In-Pictures#functors).
- In ML, *functor* is the name given a module-level constructor which can construct modules out of other modules. This is similar to a type constructor (aka generic) which can construct types out of other types or a value constructor (aka function) which can construct values out of other values. In other words, in ML, a functor is to modules what a function is to values and a type constructor is to types.
- In C++, a *functor* is any object which has an `operator()`, i.e. any object which can be called as-if it were a function. While this is almost exclusively a C++ usage of the term, this is also the way the term is used in some other programming language communities. Confusingly, this includes communities which also use the term in the first sense, so you really have to look at each individual project and each individual person how they are using the term.

**tl;dr** summary: you can call it whatever you want, as long as you define what you mean.

Comment: Impressive list.  You may add [callable](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0253-callable.md). Worth to mention that even if in the C++ circles we call it a functor,   the standard library, still names it a [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) ;-)

Comment: Impressive list, indeed. My problem was that I couldn’t construct a search string because using the word  „function“ didn’t get me anywhere. My second problem is now that, admittedly, I don’t immediately unterstand the documentation provided in the links you listed. On the first read it does *not* match the concept I have in mind. But I will take a closer look.

Comment: Just to emphasize, *please* don't name something new "functor". It already means six different things, and we don't need someone else fighting for control over that word. If you're not using it in the category theory sense, you're just complicating the word. "Function" and "Callable" are great, and so are more specific things like "Supplier" or "Predicate" (going the Java way) if you know how your function is going to be used.

Comment: @Christophe:In C++, the abstract class mentioned in the question would would be [`std::invocable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/invocable). `std::function` is a different beast. It's not abstract at all (although it's a template). It performs type erasure; it is a functor itself that can hold many different types of functors and function pointers as long as they can be invoked with roughly the same arguments.

Answer (score 3):

It may look pretentious to propose an answer after Jörg's impressive one.  But according to your comments, it seems that you're not interested in naming an object that can represent a black-box function ready to be executed,  but you are looking at a type that supports symbolic representation of functions and operations to compose functions (f+g, f o g, ...).

In this case, the most general term would be [***lambda term***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Lambda_terms). It is a concept borrowed from the lambda calculus, i.e. the theory at the foundation of computing. A lambda term can be a variable,  a function of a variable (another lambda term associated with a variable, i.e. *abstraction*), or a function applied to an expression (*application*). As you can can see, you can operate on and combine lambda terms to construct more complex ones. A more casual alternative would be ***expression***

If this terminology suits your needs (what matters here is the concept -- not the non-inutitive notation that lambda calculus uses) you could consider to the [interpreter pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_pattern) for the implementation (unless you want to engage in some more complex *[term rewriting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewriting)* algorithms).

Comment: @EricDuminil Thank you very much! That's what happens when answering in the middle of the night ;-) Corrected.

Comment: You know, this gave me an idea - maybe for what the OP is doing, the word "term" would suffice - if "expression" is seen as too casual, or potentially unclear in the context of programming? (To me "lambda term" would suggest that the domain / surrounding context has to do with lambda calculus; its use could potentially bring with it the associated semantics/rules.)

Comment: @FilipMilovanović I agree that “term” sounds less frightening than “lambda term”, and if anyway the lambdas are removed from the term notation, nobody would really miss the word “lambda” ;-)

Comment: Thanks Eric and Christophe. You are exactly right, „Lambda“ was too frightening at first glance but it actually seems to represent the concept I was looking for. I practice, however, I think I’d rather use to the term *Term* as class/interface name. Unfortunately, I can accept only one answer and I gave the credit to Jörg. But also your answer and discussion was very helpful.

Comment: @HartmutBraun Thanks for the feedback. No problem, I’m not here for the honor but to help. Knowing that this answer helped made my day ;-)

Answer (score -3):

It depends on what you are trying to do. If you are creating a function to wrap other functions in a higher level of abstraction then you might call it a [monad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)) .